# Ionic2 ionic-img-viewer throws an error

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to use ***ionic-img-viewer*** in my ionic2 app and I am getting follwoing error:

```
Runtime Error
Type ImageViewerDirective is part of the declarations of 2 modules: IonicImageViewerModule and AppModule! Please consider moving ImageViewerDirective to a higher module that imports IonicImageViewerModule and AppModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes ImageViewerDirective then import that NgModule in IonicImageViewerModule and AppModule.
```

My app.module.ts:

```
import { IonicImageViewerModule, ImageViewerDirective } from 'ionic-img-viewer';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicImageViewerModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
      deps: [Http]
    })
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    Home,
    Tutor,
    CameraTest,
    ImageDrawTextDirective,
    ImageViewerDirective
  ],

  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    Home,
    Tutor,
    CameraTest
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler, }]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

In my component I import it as:

```
import { ImageViewerDirective } from 'ionic-img-viewer';
```

and then in my HTML:

```
<img [src]="cigar_anatomy" alt="anatomy" imageViewer >
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the version of ionic2 and ionic-img-viewer that you are using?

Comment: Ionic: 2.1.18 and ionic-img-viewer: 1.2.0

Comment: dont see why you need to load ImageViewerDirective  in the app.module

Comment: I tried it as directives:[..] in my component and it gave me compile error.

Comment: but why are you adding it in the app.module?

Comment: Should I remove it from there as well? I was just following instructions as they had given. Never did it before.

Comment: Doesnt look like you need it according to the repo https://github.com/Riron/ionic-img-viewer/blob/master/ionic-img-viewer.ts

Comment: Yes it worked! Thanks a lot. Maybe you can add it as an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: meh not bothered .. glad you got it working